# Application Menu on top of Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet

In a map application based on Leaflet, I would like to have a large application menu, kind of a settings menu. I managed to put a nice button into the top right corner as a L.Control and it gets fired on a click.

The menu should position either to the left of the menu button or simply in the middle of the screen.

I am wondering whether it is best practice to use

1. a Popup,
2. a Layer,
3. another Control or
4. just position a  at the right place on the page.

Trying the latter, I found that I have to set z-index to a very high value to see it, and it feels a bit odd not to use the Leafleat features.

What would be the "right" solution to use with Leaflet?

Comment: What do you mean by small map-application ?

Comment: Nothing specific. Its a just a map shown by using Leaflet.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a full screen map, you can use https://github.com/Turbo87/leaflet-sidebar

I use it here: http://franceimage.github.io/map

Answer (score 1):

You can create a nice customized icons based toolbar using Leaflet easybutton plugin. 
You will have all the leaflet based controls (Click, hover, position etc.) to set that up as per your requirements.

Here are the implementation examples:
http://danielmontague.com/projects/easyButton.js/v1/examples/

and github repo: https://github.com/CliffCloud/Leaflet.EasyButton